How to mongodump collection with x days behind?
I'm trying to mongodump one specific collection but I need only 90 days behind. I'd to accomplish something like this:
db.collection.countDocuments({dateStart:{"$lt" : Date.now() - 90*24*60*60 * 1000 }});
Using mongodump, I do know to dump one collection like this:
mongoexport --db database --collection mycollection --username root --authenticationDatabase admin --password 'mypassword' -o /tmp/auditing.json
But I'd to mix it up with that query above.
Does anyone know if that's possible?
Thanks in advanced!

mongodump and mongoexport provide the --query option, see
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--query and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--query
Have a look at documentation, they provide examples. I guess you have to re-format the date, e.g. (in Linux):
mongoexport --db database --query='{"dateStart": { "$lt": { "$date": "'$(date --date="90 days ago" "+%FT%T%:z")'" } } }' ...

